# Issue with “gradlew” in nativescript [tns run] and [tns build]

Tags: vuejs2, nativescript

I am trying to run in emulator or build application for Android.

Software used:

- Ubuntu 16.04,
- NodeJS 10.15.3,
- Vue 3.7.0,
- Android Studio 3.4.1,

  - Build #AI-183.6156.11.34.5522156, built on May 1, 2019,
  - JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b16-5323222 amd64,
  - JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o,
  - Linux 4.4.0-146-generic.

The problem comes with the following commands:

```sh
tns run android --bundle
```

or

```sh
tns build android --bundle
```

Both ends with the following message:

```
Error: spawn ./gradlew EACCES.
```

This happens in any project, even the simplest one.

I just tested many things I have found in my search, like `chmod 777 /path/to/android-studio/path-to-file-named-gradlew`. But none of them worked.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

All files named  `gradlew` are marked as executable.

Tried also `tns remove platform android` and then `tns add platform android`, as suggested in other forums.

Comment: The problematic `gradlew` is located in `<yourProjectDir>/platforms/android/gradlew`. You could try the `chmod` there.

Comment: Thanks for reply @DimitarTachev. File there is with 777 permissions.

Comment: OK. I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 with: NodeJS 8.10.0, Vue 3.7.0, same Android Studio. There `tns buld android --bundle` command works fine.

Comment: @DimitarTachev I can build app with virtual machine, but I cannot develop the app with virtual device or physically attached device. Any idea?

Forgot to say: above mentioned installation was done on VirtualBox.

Comment: OK, Tried to download and build this: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=7YrUzj&v=7 (`npm install` and `tns install`) the `tns build android --bundle` ends with `Error: Failed to build plugin kinvey-nativescript-sdk :` `Error: spawn ./gradlew EACCES`.

Comment: I executed `tns build android --bundle --log trace`. Here is the result: http://pasted.co/fde841be

Comment: it could be caused by the Gradle cache folder if you've run some Gradle with `sudo` before. You could try cleaning the cache (`sudo rm -rf ~/.gradle`) and rerun the `tns build android --bundle` command.

Comment: I did execute the commands (~/.gradle folder was with my default user as an owner), but unfortunately `tns build android --bundle` gave me the same error message. Do you need any additional info in order to help with resolving the issue? Thank you for your effort @DimitarTachev!

Comment: Can you try:
`$ tns prepare android`
`$ cd platforms/tempPlugin/kinvey_nativescript_sdk`
`$ ./gradlew --debug --stacktrace "-p" "/home/ec/TNS/SimpleDialog/platforms/tempPlugin/kinvey_nativescript_sdk" "assembleRelease" "-PcompileSdk=android-28" "-PbuildToolsVersion=28.0.3"`


and send the output of the last command

Comment: Thank you @Vladimirov. Executing first command gave me an error `Error: Failed to build plugin kinvey-nativescript-sdk :` + `Error: spawn ./gradlew EACCES` so I decided to reboot my machine because of many installed stuff and configuration since two months of uptime. After reboot `$ tns prepare android --bundle` threw following: `Webpack compilation complete. 
Command failed: npm config get registry 
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory 
path.js:1077 
        path = process.cwd();`. I just recreated the user `ec` (removing and added new one). /continue.../

Comment: ... After short configuration `tns build android --bundle` produced wished result: a debug apk file. I face a problem with `$ tns run android --bundle` but I will investigate and in case I cannot fix it, will write here. Thanks!